# Cesium and Geoserver WMS

Tags: javascript, heatmap, cesiumjs, wms

I've got problem with wms heatmap layer in cesium. I know how to handle it in openlayers (single tile) and in leaflet (non tiled plugin) but I don't know how to handle it on 3d globe.

[image]

Here is my example code

```
const imageryLayers = this.viewer.imageryLayers;
imageryLayers.addImageryProvider(
    new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
      url: "http://localhost:8084/geoserver/test/wms/",
      layers: "points2",
      parameters: {
        service: 'WMS',
        version: '1.3.0',
        transparent: true,
        format: "image/png",
      },
    })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify GeoServer workspace name in the layers parameter.
And need to specify srs in the "parameters"
Here's the sample code.

```
const geoServerUrl = "http://localhost:8090/geoserver"
const layerName = "tiger:poly_landmarks";

const parameters = {
    version: '1.1.1',
    format: 'image/png',
    srs: 'EPSG:4326',
    transparent: true,
    "exceptions": 'application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage',
};

const webMapServiceImageryProviderOptions = {
    url: geoServerUrl + "/tiger/wms",
    layers: layerName,
    parameters: parameters,
};

const imageryLayer = new Cesium.ImageryLayer(new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider(webMapServiceImageryProviderOptions));

viewer.imageryLayers.add(imageryLayer);
```

Comment: Still it doesn't resolve the problem :( It's about single tile.